Eliminate rows without matching serial numbers
List of 82 serial numbers in Sheet1 col. "C". Want to check it against 229 serial numbers on Sheet2 col. "E".
Want to highlight red on Sheet2 for all rows without a matching SN from Sheet1.
Easy way to do this?
Trying to avoid manual input.

Try using Application.Match and IsError maybe? "Want to highlight red" - this is easily accomplished with conditional formatting, without requiring VBA.

With conditional formatting you can achieve this:
The formula in the Format values where this formula is true: (adjusted to your tables)
=ISERROR(VLOOKUP($E1,Sheet1!$C:$C,1,FALSE))  *
Applies to: =$1:$229

* Mod based on BigBen comment.

Please, try the next VBA code. It uses Vlookup between to ranges, at once, returning in an array which will be allocated to the F:F column in Sheet2 and processed to obtain the range to be highlighted:
Sub MatchSNVlookup()
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet, lastR1 As Long, rng1 As Range, ws2 As Worksheet, lastR2 As Long, rng2 As Range
 
 Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
 lastR1 = ws1.Range("C" & ws1.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last cell in C:C
                                                        'if other cells below, place here 82, instead
 
 Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
 lastR2 = ws2.Range("E" & ws2.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 
 Set rng1 = ws1.Range("C2:C" & lastR1)
 Set rng2 = ws2.Range("E2:E" & lastR2)
 
 With rng2.Offset(, 1)
    .Value = Application.VLookup(rng2.Value, rng1.Value, 1, False)         'it works on a rrays, too!
    .Replace "#N/A", ""  'it returns the string "#N/A" for not match, whidh will be replaced with the null string!
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(, -1).Interior.Color = vbYellow 'the empty cells range, Offset(,-1) = a column before is highlighted
    .Clear               'the helper range id cleared!
 End With
End Sub

